# Concatenate multiple files with two blank lines as delimiter?

Tags: text-processing, files, paste

I'm trying to join Markdown files with two newlines between each file.

I've tried using the following command:

```
paste -sd '\n\n' file1.md file2.md
```

This joins the files with a newline, but not two newlines, as I need.

What command can I use to join an arbitrary number of files with two `\n` characters between each join?

Answer (score 4):

With `paste`:

```
:|paste -sd'\n' file1.md - - file2.md
```

Answer (score 2):

With `awk` you could process *multiple* files and print a delimiter before each file (`FNR==1`) except for the first one (`NR>1`). So

```
awk '(NR>1 && FNR==1){printf ("\n\n")};1' file1.md file2.md ... fileN.md
```

concatenates the files adding the specified delimiter in-between.

---

If you don't mind a trailing delimiter in the final output, in this particular case (the delimiter is a number of empty lines) you could also do (with `gnu sed`):

```
sed -s '${G;G}' file1.md file2.md ... fileN.md
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to cuonglm's answer:

```
:|paste -sd'\n' $(sed $"s/\s/ - - /g" <<< $(ls -1|paste -sd" " -))
```

For this to work you need to have all files, that should be concatenated within one folder and at it's best sorted alphanumerical.
The output can then be redirectet to a file.

**Whats happening here?**

```
:
```

That's the true function in bash. This mostly is used for no-ops as it returns just true.

```
|
```

Thats a pipe, which takes the output of the left command and *pipes* it in the input of the right command.

```
$(sed $"s/\s/ - - /g" <<< $(ls -1|paste -sd" " -))
```

This just builds the line that is needed for paste. It will look something like

```
file1 - - file2 - - file3 - - file4 ...
```

So when paste is called it will write all lines from the listed files to standard output. When a file isn't found or called "-" paste reads from standard input and get's the TRUE value from : which is piped into paste.

Normally every file is appended a tab operator after is has been written to stdout. with the -d"\n" argument for paste the tab is exchanged with a newline.

So now paste writes the files seperated with newlines to stdout and when paste finds a "-" it takes the true and only writes the seperator to stdout - the newline.

Comment: For some reason, this one did not work for me on MacOS Mojave, even though it worked on my Linux system. I can't figure out why, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf '\n\n' | cat file1.md - file2.md
```

Something like cuonglm's, I think. Aspiring to it, anyway.

Comment: The only downside with this (and cuonglm's) - I think - is when you need to concatenate many files (e.g 20 files) as you'll have to build up the command line args. Or when trying to concatenate all `*.md`'s in a dir...

Comment: @don_crissti - Yeah, i was just thinking about that. It's not an aspect which immediately occurred to me, but i was just thinking about it. It's not so hard with the shell if you can couch it in a function where it get's it's own arg array, cause then you can just use eval with some genned string like $1 - $2 -... and so on. but still inconvenient. I wonder about `sed r\ file file` or something... it's worth chewing on.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution but works for your case:

```
echo -e `cat file1.md`"\n\n"`cat file2.md`
```

Comment: I was hoping for something more Unix-like which would simply accept multiple files and join them with a given delimiter.

Comment: I am not able to think of any Unix-like solution which would simply accept files and join them with a given delimiter. Perhaps, you could write a small shell function for this.

Answer (score 0):

With a newer GNU `awk`:

```
awk '1; ENDFILE {print "\n"}' files...
```