# print empty line in sed output when passing multiple filenames

Tags: sed, filenames, parameter

I'm doing some placeholder replacements in various files that I'm feeding to `ldapadd`, to add new entries to an LDAP directory:

```
sed \
    -e 's/%%FOO%%/whatever/g' \
    -e 's/%%BAR%%/other thing/g \
    file1.ldif.template \
    file2.ldif.template \
    | ldapadd -x -D 'cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com' -W
```

The problem I'm having with this is that if there is not an empty line at the end of `file1.ldif.template`, the first record in `file2` is concatenated to the last record in `file1`, and in `ldif` files different records should be separated by at least 1 newline.

Of course I could add an empty line at the end of `file1`, but that is very easy to fail in the future if some other developer (or their editors) remove the trailing newlines.

So to summarize. Current (simplified) sed output:

```
dn: cn=record1_file1,dc=example,dc=com
cn: record1_file1

dn: cn=record2_file1,dc=example,dc=com
cn: record2_file1
dn: cn=record1_file2,dc=example,dc=com
cn: record1_file2

dn: cn=record2_file2,dc=example,dc=com
cn: record2_file2
```

Desired (simplified) output:

```
dn: cn=record1_file1,dc=example,dc=com
cn: record1_file1

dn: cn=record2_file1,dc=example,dc=com
cn: record2_file1

dn: cn=record1_file2,dc=example,dc=com
cn: record1_file2

dn: cn=record2_file2,dc=example,dc=com
cn: record2_file2
```

I'm working on linux (fedora 21) using GNU sed. Portability is not a concern (but i'll prefer a portable solution over a GNU solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU sed `-s (--separate)` extension, you can append an empty newline after each filename (line addresses refer to each filename, instead of treating all the input as one longer stream, similar to `awk`'s `FNR` and `NR` variables)

```
sed \
    -s \
    -e '$a\\' \
    -e 's/%%FOO%%/whatever/g' \
    -e 's/%%BAR%%/other thing/g \
    file1.ldif.template \
    file2.ldif.template \
    | ldapadd -x -D 'cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com' -W
```

So using `-s` with `-e '$a\\'` is what makes `sed` insert a newline at the end of all input files.

Answer (score 2):

An easy and portable way is to insert a file with an empty line in the 
file arguments:

```
# create file with one empty line
echo > emptyline.txt

# calling sed:
sed -e 's/%%FOO%%/whatever/g' \
    -e 's/%%BAR%%/other thing/g \
    file1.ldif.template \
    emptyline.txt \
    file2.ldif.template \ 
    | ...
```

Some shells support also this:

```
sed -e 's/%%FOO%%/whatever/g' \
    -e 's/%%BAR%%/other thing/g \
    file1.ldif.template \
    <(echo) \
    file2.ldif.template \ 
    | ...
```

Comment: This is becoming rather inconvenient with many file names (as mentioned [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204224/join-multiple-files-with-two-blank-lines/204232#comment360998_212934)) or even complex if the list of files is passed to sed via xargs/find...

Comment: @don_crissti I added a possiblity with `xargs` for many files.

Comment: Errhh... I was talking about passing _multiple_ file names to a single `sed` invocation; that looks like some complex code that spawns a shell which runs `cat`, `echo` & `sed` for each file - but then, if you're processing each file separately (that is, one `sed` per file) you can simply do `-exec sed -e 'blah-blah' -e '$a\\' {} \;` (which is exactly what OP does but with a single `gnu sed` invocation)

Comment: @don_crissti yes your are correct, it does not make sense, I removed it.