# Merging text files and adding separator

Tags: text-processing, scripting

I want to add a separator like this "==============" and a blank new line

I tried to do this, but failed  and causes high CPU usage. i mean the cpu become rotate ery fast and noisy when i run the script

This needs to be for around 100000 text files.

this is the code that I use

```
#!/bin/bash
for F in *.txt ; do
    type "$F"
    echo .
    echo ========
    echo . 
done >> Combined.txt;
```

please advice

Comment: See [Concatenate multiple files with two blank lines as delimiter?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/204224/22142) and the linked questions/answers.

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify your commands as follows:

```
  #!/bin/bash
  for file in *.txt; do
  cat $file >> Combined.txt
  printf '\n\n=========\n\n' >> Combined.txt
  done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to do it for thousands of files,  you may want to avoid running several commands per file. With GNU `awk`:

```
printf '%s\0' ./*.txt | xargs -r0 gawk '
  BEGINFILE {if (NR) print "\n==========\n"};1' > combined.out
```

Don't give a `.txt` extension to the output file if you're going to put it in the same directory, or it's going to be selected as an input file and causing an infinite loop (probably your problem in the first place).

Or use a shell where `cat` is builtin like `ksh93`:

```
#! /bin/ksh93 -
firstpass=true
for file in *.txt; do
  "$firstpass" || print '\n===========\n'
  firstpass=false
  command /opt/ast/bin/cat < "$file"
done > combined.out
```

All those commands in the loop are built-in, so running them doesn't involve forking new processes nor loading external executable, so that would make the performance tolerable.

Answer (score 0):

## Using `FNR` and `NR` in `awk`

```
#!/bin/bash

outfile="$( mktemp combined.txt.XXXXXX )"

echo "Output file: ${outfile}"

awk 'FNR==1 && NR>1 { printf("\n%s\n\n","========") } 1' *.txt > "${outfile}"

echo "Finished."
```

A line-by-line description:

```
outfile="$( mktemp combined.txt.XXXXXX )"
```

Use `mktemp` to create an empty new file with a unique name (eg, `combined.txt.HDpgMn`).  You can use more `X` characters for a longer random suffix.  Enclose the command in `"$(`...`)"` to store the new file's name in the variable `outfile`.

```
echo "Saving to file: ${outfile}"
```

Print the name of the output file.  (When the script has finished, you may wish to rename the output file to remove the string of random characters following the `.txt`.)

```
awk 'FNR==1 && NR>1 { printf("\n%s\n\n","========") } 1' *.txt > "${outfile}"
```

Print...

- a blank line,
- a short line of "=" characters,
- and another blank line

...at the start of each input file, except for the first input file.  `FNR` counts the input file line numbers, resetting at the start of each file.  `NR` counts the line numbers and does not reset.

In the `awk` statement, the `1` just before the closing single quotation mark evaluates to `TRUE` for every line, and performs the default action of printing that line.  (In other words, `awk '1'` works like `cat`.)

```
echo "Finished."
```

Inform the user when the script is done.  (Not strictly necessary, since you'll see the command prompt anyway, but it doesn't hurt.)

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply

```
printf "\n\n=====\n\n" > XTMP
cat $(printf "%s XTMP " *.txt) > combined.tmp
```

Put the separator into a temp file, and make use of `printf`'s feature to repeat the formatting string for every argument it finds, so the `cat` command will look like

```
cat 1.txt XTMP 2.txt XTMP ... n.txt XTMP
```

You may run into system limits (e.g. LINE_MAX), though...